# Why Stack Overflow C++ labeled questions get so frequently downvoted?

Tags: discussion

Why do C++ related topics get downvoted so badly? Other topics get equally silly, non well stated, non-clear, not formatted questions, but honestly I have not seen this hostility elsewhere. It is obvious that these practices only harm the community and they actively discourage people (specially beginners) to participate.

Is there a mechanism to prevent this type of toxic behavior?

By the way, you can check right now the new 5 pages of questions in C++, and you will only find 0 or negative scores.

[image: random example]

Comment: Because luckily the C++ tag is heavily patrolled by quality minded users and every question that can be answered by taking a course, reading the specs or a simple Google search will be removed from the site as soon as possible. That will guarantee that the useful content can be found by visitors. This is very much by design.

Comment: So the rest of the communities lack quality minded users. Sure.

Comment: "Why do c++ related topics get downvoted so badly?" - Because they all suck? Stackoverflow has very high quality standards. And most questions don't meet those standards.

Comment: Yeah, certainly true for example Android and PHP. The upvote bots outnumber the few that try to keep those tags clean

Comment: How do you want people to react to "silly, non well stated, non-clear, not formatted questions"? If you look at the rate of downvotes per view it is not bad, 10% downvoted at worst, 90% did not downvote. And even that question got 3 answers. Don't see what you are getting at here. If anything you should ask why bad questions get only 10% downvoted and answers too.

Comment: Siimilar result if you search for [Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).  It's not the language, *it's the poor quality of the questions.*

Comment: Eternal September, bad unis teaching abysmal C++ practices, and students treating SO as "do my homework" website.

Comment: Note that we as a C++ community can appreciate good questions, which is why most of SO questions in Hot Network Questions are about C++.

Comment: see [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601)

Comment: The c++ community is a very active one and does a pretty good job regarding demand of quality questions (as long mods leave us to do ;-) )
Sometimes not literally nice, I have to admit (heating in my isolation bunker).

Comment: _"So the rest of the communities lack quality minded users. Sure."_ Actually, yes.

Answer (score 17):

> Why do c++ related topics get downvoted so badly?

Because the C++ community cares about having quality content, answering quality questions, and helping people that have problems with their questions fix those problems, rather than providing low quality answers to low quality questions.

> Other topics get equally silly, non well stated, non-clear, not formatted questions, but honestly I have not seen this hostility elsewhere.

It's not hostility, it's them being helpful, having standards and values, and enforcing them.  This is how it's able to produce quality content.

It's also worth noting that some tag communities do actually have differing amounts of low quality content.  They all invariably have some, but there are those with more than others.  When you see tags with a higher or lower average score it's a *combination* of the quality of the questions in those tags, and also the standards that those communities hold themselves to, not just one or the other.

> It is obvious that these practices only harm the community

Oh, and how so?  Care to provide evidence to back up this assertion?

> and they actively discourage people (specially beginners) to participate.

It discourages people that consistently provide low quality content, yes.  When given feedback that their contributions are problematic they can either choose to fix the content, and improve the quality of their contributions, or they may choose not to.  Either choice is preferable than them continuing to provide low quality content.

> Is there a mechanism to prevent this type of toxic behavior?

It's not toxic.  It's helpful.  And we don't want to prevent it.  We want to *encourage* people to downvote bad posts, to close questions that merit closure.  These are precisely the mechanisms that have helped the site create the quality content that it has, and why so many other sites largely fail to provide useful content.

Comment: I still do not get the argument about the unique stupidity of users submitting c++ related questions. Do you have some scientific evidence for your claims?

Comment: @nikferrari Why do you think it's just C++? Have you taken a look at Android and PHP?

Comment: @nikferrari I made no such argument.  You were quite right in saying that other tags also have lots of low quality content.  Some are better or worse than others in the quality of the questions posted, but they all do have some amounts of low quality content.  There are a number of tags with a reputation of having much lower quality questions than what you'd expect out of, say, the C++ tag.

Comment: I cannot comment on Android and PHP since I do not follow them. I cannot judge based on a single search.

Comment: @nikferrari They're tags with a reputation for having *lots* of bad content.  (And also for not effectively moderating their content, which isn't a coincidence.)

Comment: @nikferrari could it have anything to do with the fact that C++ is taught in schools, so the tag gets a lot of junk from students that only want to be spoon-fed and can't be bothered to *research* a wee bit before asking on SO?

Comment: @Meta'sMug That's true of *lots* of languages, and those languages all do get lots of bad questions for exactly that reason.